# Matlab real time plot

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab and I want to plot some data in real time.
My approach was follows:

```
figure;
hold on;

for i = 1:1000;
   plot(i, i);
   drawnow;
end
```

But it has poor performance.

I also found a suggestion here on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3118918/1066838
but only the last set data are drawn, so I see always only one point on the figure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of doing a high-level `plot` call, consider adjusting the [line handle properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/line_props.html), more specifically the `XData` and `YData`, in the loop:

```
figure(1);
lHandle = line(nan, nan); %# Generate a blank line and return the line handle

for i = 1:1000
    X = get(lHandle, 'XData');
    Y = get(lHandle, 'YData');

    X = [X i];
    Y = [Y i];

    set(lHandle, 'XData', X, 'YData', Y);
end
```

Doing it this way, a `tic`/`toc` before/after the code gives 0.09 seconds; a naive `plot` as you have, as you have probably seen, gives a runtime of nearly 20 seconds.

Note that I only used `get` in this example to generate the dataset; I assume for a real time plot you've got some `DatasetX` and `DatasetY` to plot, so you'll need to work your data accordingly. But in the end, once you've got the dataset you want to plot at a particular time, just `set` the line's entire `XData` and `YData`.

Finally, note that this `set` call gets a bit unwieldy for very large datasets, since we have to set the the lines' data every time rather than append to it. (But it's certainly still faster than using `plot`.) This might be good enough depending on how frequently your dataset changes. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413320/matlab-best-way-to-dynamically-update-a-line-handles-xdata-and-ydata) for more details.

---

**EDIT**: As of MATLAB R2014b, the [`animinatedline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/animatedline-object.html) object makes it easier to plot points from streaming data:

> Animated line objects optimize line animations by accumulating data from a streaming data source. After you create the initial animated line using the animatedline function, you can add new points to the line without having to redefine the existing points. Modify the appearance of the animated line by setting its properties.

Comment: Strangly, for me it does not plot realtime, but waits until computation is done and THEN displays the plot. Any idea why?

Comment: Shouldn't be there a `drawnow` command after `set` (and before `end`)?

Comment: Maybe. It's always worked for me without the `drawnow`, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

To improve preformance you should use clf, it clears the figure. Otherwise all the plots stack on each other.

If you want to do `plot(x,y)` in real time, you should do:

```
figure;
hold on;

for i = 1:1000;
   clf;
   plot(x(1:i), y(1:i));
   drawnow;
end
```

Comment: @SamuelNLP, it definitely helps. I have used it multiple times, and removing the `clf`, makes it really slow. Try it out.