# MATLAB - how to use event.eventData, and efficiently

Tags: oop, matlab

For background information and context for my question, please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7413320/238644).

Notice in the `updatePlot()` method of my `DynamicPlotter` code, I kind of "reach into" a `DynamicDataset` property, as follows:

```
function updatePlot(obj, propNum)
    X = get(obj.LH(propNum), 'XData');
    Y = get(obj.LH(propNum), 'YData');

    X(end+1) = obj.(dynProps{propNum}).newestData(1);
    Y(end+1) = obj.(dynProps{propNum}).newestData(2);

    set(obj.LH(propNum), 'XData', X, 'YData', Y);
end
```

`updatePlot` is a listener callback. Rather than "reach in" to go get the `newestData`, I am wondering if it would be more efficient to have the data "presented" to the callback with [`event.eventData`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/event.eventdata.html). But I am unsure of (a) how to even use `event.eventData` (the example provided in the documentation isn't very clear to me), and (b) if this yields better or worse performance.

So I guess my main question is, what's the best way for `updatePlot()` to access the `newestData` as depicted in the method above: "reaching in and retrieving it" or using `event.eventData` to "send" the data point to the function to plot?

I hope this wasn't terribly ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to have a class that defines an event (in MyClass.m):

```
classdef MyClass < handle
  events
    % Event
    MyEvent
  end

  methods
    function obj = MyClass
      % Constructor
    end
  end
end
```

Then you need to create your own EventData subclass (in MyEventData.m):

```
classdef MyEventData < event.EventData
  properties (Access = public)
    % Event data
    Data
  end

  methods
    function this = MyEventData(data)
      % Constructor
      this.Data = data;
    end
  end
end
```

Attach your data to an instance of the event data class (in a script file):

```
X = 1:10;
Y = 1:10;
data = struct('XData', X, 'YData', Y);
eventData = MyEventData(data);
```

And fire the event from your `obj` and have a listener listen to it:

```
obj = MyClass;
l = addlistener(obj, 'MyEvent', @(evtSrc,evtData)disp(evtData.Data));
notify(obj, 'MyEvent', eventData)
```

Anytime you call `notify(...)`, the `evtData` argument in your listener callback will have your data in its `Data` property:

```
>> notify(obj, 'MyEvent', eventData)
    XData: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
    YData: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```